# In Kotlin, can't emit data as separate variables to socket server

Tags: android, kotlin, socket.io

From my app that was written by Kotlin:

```
var args = JSONArray()
    args.put(uid)
    args.put(tic)

    socket.emit("join_game",args)
```

From server side, the code is:

```
socket.on('join_game',function(uid, tic){
```

As expect, it should send uid and tic to server, but it only send the data as "{uid},{tic}" to uid in server only, the tic become null at that time.

I also tried with args as JSONObject and Array < String >. Both of them were failed. It sent object type and java.string type to server.

From the guide popup, I can emit in 3 ways

```
socket.emit(event: String!, vararg args: Any!)
socket.emit(event: String!, args: Array<(out) Any!>!, ack: Ack!)
socket.emit(event: String!, args: Array<(out) Any!>!, ack: ((args:Array<(out) Any!>!) -> Unit)!
```

The socket that I used for my app is com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0

Note: The server code is correct because I can send data as 2 variables from my ios version to server.

Comment: How does the listener look like (the implementation after `function(uid, tic){`)? It would be fundamental to know what the server expect to be passed.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [code](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java/blob/964a66fc1c57042a37301ec426ffef266bfc0f56/src/main/java/io/socket/client/Socket.java#L181), `socket.emit` wraps the `args` into a `JSONArray`, so the way you've called it here would actually end up with a `JSONArray` inside a `JSONArray` (which may account for the output on the server).

If instead you use the first signature, you can actually pass the arguments directly like so:

```
socket.emit("join_game", uid, tic)
```

At a basic level, the `vararg` keyword means you can pass any number of arguments in place of the single "argument" (in this case, `args`). More information about this concept can be found [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs).